# Similarity between two sets of points as a level of a path overlay

Tags: correlation, similarities

**This question has an answer at:** https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49923/how-do-i-compare-two-maps-to-determine-which-is-better  (buried deep in comments so copied here)

Say I have two sets, A and B, with a different amount of X,Y points

Is there a way to calculate how similar the data is?

So something like this would be ~65%?, because they partial overlay.

```
|                                  B8
|                                  
|                                 B7
|                               [A7]
|B1                        B6[A6]
|   B2               B5[A5]
|        B3   B4[A4]
|        [A3]
|
|     [A2]
|   
|
|   [A1]
|____________________________________
```

And data like the following would have a low percentage even though they are similar. they are not overlaying.

```
|                B6
|             B5
|          B4
|       B3
|    B2
| B1
|                         [A7]
|                     [A6]
|                 [A5]
|             [A4]
|         [A3]
|     [A2]
| [A1]
|____________________________________
```

Also this data would have a low percentage, even though they "intersect"

```
|  B1
|                     [A6]
|       B2
|                 [A5]
|           B3
|             [A4]
|               B4
|         [A3]
|                  B5
|     [A2]
|                      B6
| [A1]
|____________________________________
```

And this **data would be almost 100%, because their path overlays**

```
|
|                             B5
|                            [A5]
|
|
|                            B4
|                         [A4]
|                  [A3]B3
|         [A2]B2
|     B1
|  [A1]
|____________________________________
```

Another example of the issue is. Say I record a set [A] of points (latitude, and longitude) while I'm driving. I drive from my house on to the highway and to work. A friend also records a set [B] of points from his house to the **SAME** strip of highway I drove, to his office. The data would look like the **first graph**. Is there a way to calculate how similar the data (geolocation) is?

Is it possible to calculate a percentage of similiarity between the two sets of points? I've looked into the following methods, but can't get it to work:

- Spearman/Pearson's Correlation: I think this is the closest thing I'm looking for, but it only compares two variables, instead of sets of points
- Linear approx.: The problem with this is that the data is definitely NOT linear
- Canonical Correlations Analysis: Not sure how to use it...

Comment: Can you define "similarity"? In your example, would you consider the points "similar"?

Comment: I'm not sure which word to use, similarity or correlation. I updated the question with more examples. Essentially, if the points in the two sets are numerically close, it has a high percentage.

Comment: Surely more than "numerically close" is involved here, because the examples involve point sets of different cardinalities. You seem to be searching for some sense of "close as subsets of the Euclidean plane." But since "close" can be measured in so many ways, you need to be more specific about what it really means for two subsets to be "close." For instance, in the first two examples the two sets have comparable Hausdorff distances.

Comment: @whuber i agree, it's more than numerically close, more like "visually?" or "shape?" close. Essentially, I'm trying to match paths.

Comment: In the absence of a precise formulation of your problem, editing your question to include more information about your application would be welcome: that could guide respondents towards appropriate suggestions.

Comment: This question has answers [on our GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/49923/664).

Comment: @whuber thanks! I found the answer from your link. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/52148